# How do I download and extract a tar in one command, while extracting only a single file to a specific location?

Tags: linux, command-line, wget, tar, curl

I'm trying to accomplish what it says in the title ... but for the life of me I can't figure out the magic invocation.

The LLVM archive I am downloading contains the path `clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-format` which I want to extract to a specified location.

I'm trying this:

```
mkdir outdir && curl -L 'https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-10.0.0/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz' | tar -xz clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-format --directory outdir/ --strip-components=2
```

But this places nothing in `outdir` and meanwhile creates the path to extract in the current working directory (which is what I'm trying to avoid with `--strip-components`).

When I move `--strip-components` to the front, it strips the path, but places the result in the current directory, ignoring `--directory`.

What is the correct way to do this?

---

**End goal:** Extract `clang-format` binary to `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `--strip-components` and `-C` options need to precede the file to extract, otherwise they are silently ignored.

I suppose the man page hints at this

```
tar -x [-f ARCHIVE] [OPTIONS] [MEMBER...]
```

But in some contexts (https://askubuntu.com/a/45354/596667) it seems to be ok at the end.

The correct command line is thus

```
mkdir outdir && curl -L 'https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-10.0.0/clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04.tar.xz' | tar  --directory outdir/ --strip-components=2 -xz clang+llvm-10.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin/clang-format
```